# Angular 2 not working with Bootstrap 3 or 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, ng2-bootstrap

I started to implement my own Angular 2 app and I want to use Bootstrap framework. The problem is that I cannot plug Bootstrap with Angular 2. I saw that many people have the same problem but I didn't find solution. 
I installed bootstrap 3 via npm and I get min.css from index.html.

But when I put a dropdown menu in my code, this is not clickable:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
     <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using `ng2-bootstrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
In system.config.ts is needed to add these 2 lines inside packages.

```
packages: {
     'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
     'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```

And this line inside map

```
'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
```

After that you should import ng2-bootstrap in the appropriate module and it works!

Answer (score 2):

In order for Bootstrap 3/4 to be fully functional you need to include also **.js** sources. By including **.css** file(s) you only reference the styling part of the bootstrap. For Angular(2) I suggest using plain CSS/SCSS files bundled in the project and adding one of specialized Angular2-Bootstrap packages additionally like: `ng-bootstrap` or `ng2-bootstrap`.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the angular and bootstrap libs.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- IE polyfills, keep the order please -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<!-- Agular 2 -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<!-- Agular 2 Router -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/router.dev.js"></script>
 <!-- Config Agular 2 and Typescript -->
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript', 
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/angulartypescript/n305zyya/